# Internal Iterator in c#

Tags: c#

How can I implement internal iterator in c# ?

Comment: Have you looked into the new Reactive Framework? It might have the sort of gear in it that you need.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this definition](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?InternalIterator) of "internal iterator" on the c2 wiki:

> An Internal Iterator is a
>   [HigherOrderFunction](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HigherOrderFunction) that takes a
>   collection and a function and applies
>   the function to every element of the
>   collection

Assuming that's what you want, here's how to do it in C#:

```
static void ForEach<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
{
   foreach (T item in enumerable)
   {
      action(item);
   }
}
```

Example use:

```
Action<int> printer = x => Console.WriteLine(x);
var numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3};
ForEach(numbers, printer);
```

Answer (score 2):

[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/cyrusn/archive/2004/06/07/149893.aspx) is an example

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something that does the `foreach` (or equivalent) for you (in the most appropriate way for the data)? Like `List<T>.ForEach`? This is where delegates come to the fore; just pass an `Action<T>`, and apply to each in turn.

```
public void SomeMethod(Action<MyDataType> action) {
    {for each item} // pseudo#
        action(item);
    {end}
}
```

I've avoided using `foreach` in the above deliberately, as this most commonly applies to scenarios where `foreach` isn't already provided.

However; IMO, since C# (from 2.0 onwards) has `yield return` syntax (iterator blocks), it is easier just to support `IEnumerable<T>`. You could of course add a `ForEach` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` ;-p Internal iterators may have been attractive in .NET 1.1 (C# 1.2) where (correctly) writing an iterator was *incredibly* painful.